# Click button with oncick javascript not working in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, ide

I have two buttons that are linked to a onclick javascript (see below)

```html
<button 
    type="button" 
    class="ui-datepicker-current ui-state-default ui-priority-primary ui-corner-all" 
    onclick="DP_jQuery_1480511128847.datepicker._gotoToday('#historical-datepicker');"
>Current Month</button> 
<button 
    type="button" 
    class="ui-datepicker-close ui-state-default ui-priority-primary ui-corner-all" 
    onclick="DP_jQuery_1480511128847.datepicker._hideDatepicker();"
>DONE</button>
```

Clicking on DONE should update the page with new content. It does work normally but not with selenium IDE test.
Selenium find the correct button but it does not trigger the load of the new page.
All locators work when I click on Find: (see locators) :

1. `xpath=(//button[@type='button'])[3]`
2. `//div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[2]/button[2]`
3. `//button[2]`

The div which contains the button is hidden at the start of the page. It is displayed by clicking on a field in the page.

Any ideas why the page does not load with selenium IDE?

Another thing, when I play the selenium IDE test, there is no error reported. And if I manually click in any part of the page, the new page loads.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have done a bit of rewording to make your question more readable, and also tweaked the code formatting so that it is clearer - please see the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting. If you have any more improvements you could make, please feel free to [edit] the question further; on this site, editing and re-editing is encouraged. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you really much for your precious help. It is better.